# Can someone please explain this CMD batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
set SourceSCMPasswd=abc
set HATCONTESTING=yes 


for /f %%a in ('dir /AD /b')  do VssConverter.exe analyze %%a\settings.xml & move VSSAnalysisReport.xml %%a & move usermap.xml %%a
```

I know that it does the following commands:
    1) Run VssConverter.exe analyze on %%a\settings.xml
    2) Move VSSAnalysisReport.xml to %%a
    3) Move usermap.xml to %%a

The problem is that when a folder in the directory has a space in its name, like AMEX Mailer for example, the variable %%a only contains AMEX but excludes the second part. How do I make it include the whole name?

Comment: `help for` has all answers for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default token delimiter for FOR /F is `<tab>` and `<space>`. You want to preserve the entire string as a single token, so you want no delimiter ("DELIMS=") The default EOL option is `;`. Any line that begins with `;` will be ignored. Though unlikely, it is possible for a file name to begin with `;`. You want to set EOL to some character that cannot appear in a name. Good candidates are `:`, `*`, and `?`.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ...
```

Comment: OP uses `for /f` to list/process directories. Won't `for /D` fit that better?

Comment: it's not my code, I was just given this batch file to run. I don't really know how these work

Comment: thanks dbenham I added that segment after for /f and it worked perfectly

Comment: @wmz - I think you are correct that FOR /D is a better and simpler solution for this case. But there are situations where a simple FOR will not work and FOR /F with DIR command is just the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ...
```

Comment: This does not solve anything. I assume you think \n will be interpretted as a new line character. That does not work in batch. It will break on any "n" or "\" character, which is definitely not what the OP wants. The backslash is ok, but certainly not the "n".

Comment: you're right.  I didn't notice that in my test a few filenames where broken on 'n'.  I'm changing the answer to delim=